# Javascript Bookmarklet - remove spaces from input

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to this so please take it easy on me.

I have a javascript bookmark that I use to look up tracking number for parcels on Purolators website (Canadian shipping company). What I want it to do is to take the input (tracking number) and remove any spaces in it before opening the URL. The tracking site is stupid and uses spaces as delimiters for new tracking numbers.

Also, as a bonus, can this be made to open in a new tab?

```
javascript:var%20trackID%20=%20escape(prompt('Enter%20Tracking%20#'));window.location='https://eshiponline.purolator.com/SHIPONLINE/Public/Track/TrackingDetails.aspx?pin='%20+%20trackID;
```

I have tried adding `trackID%20=%20trackID.replace(/\s+/g,%20'');` before the `window.location` but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `escape` in this scenario. This is actually replacing your spaces with %20 special characters which is why your `replace` wasn't working

Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp for more info.

Your corrected code should be something like

```
javascript:var trackID=prompt('Enter%20Tracking%20#').replace(/ /g,"");window.location='https://eshiponline.purolator.com/SHIPONLINE/Public/Track/TrackingDetails.aspx?pin='+trackID;
```